# Laravel Dynamic routing with if else condition

Tags: laravel, vue.js, routes

I previously had a codeigniter website with link look like this
Domain.com/ABCRestaurant

Now I recently created a new SPA website based on laravel and vue router

I want to make sure all the old link properly redirects to the new website.

So basically when someone opens 
Domain.com/ABCRestaurant I want to check if "ABCRestuarant" exists in my restaurant table then either just open the view page to load it's products or redirects to old like i.e /ordernow/product/i/ABCRestaurant

however if ABCRestaurant doesn't exits then I want to follow my usual routing for spa which currently looks like this

```
Route::any('{all}', function () {
return view('home');
})
->where(['all' => '.*']);
```

Can someone help me with this?

Comment: Routing with if else is not proper for laravel. Alternative for that is using [middlewares](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/middleware).

Comment: @BonishKoirala ok I'll check that. Thanks